# PyQt6 crashes with QBitmap()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt6

```
from PyQt6 import QtGui as qg
bitmap = qg.QBitmap(800, 600)
```

crashes with Error message:
QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap

I want to setup a QMainWindow with two layers. The lower level should be a QImage and the top layer should be a QBitmap where you can just "delete" pixels by manipulating the alpha channel.

I tryed to restart my computer, I reinstalled all of my requirements.
Furthermore I ran the code on another computer where it works just fine.

Comment: The error clearly says what the problem is. You cannot create a QPixmap (from which QBitmap inherits) without an existing QApplication instance. Do that after doing the canonical `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`.

Comment: It works on another computer with the exact same code

Comment: That's unlikely: Qt **always** checks if a QApplication exists before creating a QPixmap, so, except for the rare (but not impossible) case of a bug that affects a specific Qt version, you're probably using/importing that script under different conditions we're not aware of. And even if that wasn't the case, different OS (and OS versions) can have slight differences that "allow" some aspects: for instance, it's possible to create a QIcon under Windows and Linux without a QApplication, but doing that on macOS will result in a fatal crash. The point remains: a QApplication **must** exist.